# Debugging native code in Android Studio: LLDB server not found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to debug my native Android application, sometimes I get this IDE internal error:

```
java.lang.Throwable: LLDB server not found
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:126)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.newSessionStarter(ConnectLLDBTask.java:360)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.access$200(ConnectLLDBTask.java:91)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask$3.createDebugProcess(ConnectLLDBTask.java:598)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.testing.CidrLauncher.startDebugProcess(CidrLauncher.java:29)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrCommandLineState.startDebugProcess(CidrCommandLineState.java:30)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrRunner$1.start(CidrRunner.java:63)
at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.XDebuggerManagerImpl.startSession(XDebuggerManagerImpl.java:201)
at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.XDebuggerManagerImpl.startSession(XDebuggerManagerImpl.java:162)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrRunner.startDebugSession(CidrRunner.java:56)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.launchCidrDebugger(ConnectLLDBTask.java:628)
at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.launchDebugger(ConnectLLDBTask.java:296)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.ConnectDebuggerTask.lambda$perform$0(ConnectDebuggerTask.java:90)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil$14.run(UIUtil.java:3144)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:758)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The problem is not in the application itself, nor the Android Studio, I think. To get it to work, I sometimes have to disable then enable again the USB debugging mode on my device, detach and attach the USB cable again or sometimes even restart my device. I don't want to do it every time I need to debug my code because it is just a waste of time an my nerves. Anybody knows the cause or the solution of this weird problem?

Comment: have you tried different cable? or different device? sometimes simple solutions are the best

Comment: I did try changing my cable, but it did not help. At the moment, I do not have an extra device so this is not possible for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if its not the mobile's issue nor the cable's issue, then its the usb port issue of your laptop or system.

Comment: I have also tried to attach the cable to another USB port, no change.